# Compiling kernel in Ubuntu on EC2 (no errors, but no image and unchanged after restart)

Tags: compilation, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04

I need to update the kernel timer on my Ubuntu Lucid (10.04) server on EC2 (with EBS) from 250HZ to 1000HZ, to improve voip call quality.

From what I've read, the way to do that is to download the kernel source code, configure it, then install it.

I've found several decent tutorials that are fairly specific to my setup, the best of which are:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile
- http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/05/05/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-lucid-kernel/
- http://crashcourse.ca/introduction-linux-kernel-programming/intermission-building-new-ubuntu-1004-kernel-free-lesson

That's led to me to the following sets of commands, which all run nicely, making the .deb files with no obvious errors. But then when I restart the server the timer frequency hasn't been updated.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get build-dep linux
sudo apt-get install fakeroot build-essential
sudo apt-get install crash kexec-tools makedumpfile kernel-wedge
sudo apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev asciidoc binutils-dev kernel-package

cd /usr/src
sudo apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)

cd linux-*
sudo make menuconfig
# Processor type and features -> Timer frequency -> change to 1000HZ -> Exit -> Exit -> Yes (Save)

fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers
fakeroot debian/rules binary-indep   #This does the headers, docs, and source

#check deb 2-3 files were created
cd ..
ls *.deb

sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb
#reboot
```

**EDIT**

Spent some time with jjohansen on irc #ubuntu-kernel, and was able to find my mistake with his help - looks like I should have done the configuration step in between the clean and build. Also, he recommended to always use the source from git rather than the package, so these are the new commands to do in the middle of what I had above:

```
cd /usr/src
# This is 700mb so it takes a while to download and set up
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid.git
cd ubuntu*
git checkout --track -b ec2 origin/ec2

fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs
fakeroot debian/rules binary
#Takes about 40min
```

Comment: Today I've tried doing these same steps on a plain vanilla Ubuntu Lucid 64bit large instance on EC2. About the same results. So if anyone is able to try this for me you should be able to reproduce using the normal 64bit Lucid EBS AMI on www.alestic.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Johansen (kernel hacker at Canonical) believes that you should be able to build and run your own kernel on an EC2 instance with Ubuntu.

See jjohansen's notes in this 1000Hz EC2 kernel request I had submitted back in 2009:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-ec2/+bug/365233

You will want to make sure that you are starting with a recent Ubuntu AMI that uses pvgrub.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I'd seen that page a couple of times, and had hoped to catch the eye of either yourself or Scott Moser. That was where I got the link to the BuildYourOwnKernel instructions that I pasted above. And it was after following the steps in that (linked) page that I got as far as I have and got stuck. Do you think I'm best to contact John/Scott directly? or try the irc #ubuntu-kernel he mentioned? The more I work on this the more I think it is only my first problem above that applies, and that something is wrong with the kernel source code (or something missing on my server.)

Comment: John hangs out on #ubuntu-kernel as jjohansen and there are other experts there, too.

Comment: What about 12.04 (Precise)? There is no ec2 branch for it. Any solutions to that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Eric Hammond for the heads up,

Which kernel you are going to need will depend on which version of Ubuntu you are using.  For Lucid - Maverick you will need to use the -ec2 kernel source.  The support needed was moved into the regular kernel tree for natty and oneric.

So you will need to do

```
 sudo apt-get source linux-ec2
```

or

```
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid.git
```

```
cd into the source directory

fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

For Lucid you will also have to make sure you have a done an update or are using a current image, as support for pv-grub was add after Lucid was release.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan @user1043670 - linux-ec2 only brought down 5kb. Git brought down the full thing, but after running `fakeroot debian-rules binary` it had built the headers, doc, source, and tools, but still no image (and after dpkg and a restart it's still on the old kernel.) I'm a bit wary of that anyway, as I don't know what config changes are be needed for running on EC2. Yes I'm on the newer aki with pvgrub. Also, I've just added a comment on my post above about having tried on a plain vanilla Lucid on EC2. Are you in a position to try on a Lucid instance on ec2 yourself? Any other ideas?

Comment: Am I right that the image deb file is needed? Or is it not needed and my problem is with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing Redzarf's terminal commands including his edit plus a couple small necessary additions, heres what worked for me on a Amazon ec2 vanilla install of Ubuntu Server Cloud Guest 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) 64x

```
# Make yourself root
sudo su

# Update source list:
aptitude update

# Upgrade everything:
aptitude upgrade 

# Install dependencies:
apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
apt-get build-dep linux
apt-get install fakeroot build-essential
apt-get install crash kexec-tools makedumpfile kernel-wedge
apt-get install libncurses5 libncurses5-dev
apt-get install libelf-dev asciidoc binutils-dev kernel-package
apt-get install git-core

cd /usr/src
git clone git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-lucid.git 
cd ubuntu*
git checkout --track -b ec2 origin/ec2
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs

# Configuration window should now appear, do the following:

Select YES

# Navigate to:
Processor type and features -> Timer frequency
# Select the 1000HZ frequency 
Exit 
Exit 
Yes (Save)

#After saving and returning to prompt it may ask you to do it again for i386, select yes and repeat!

# Recompile:
fakeroot debian/rules binary 

#Check if your deb 2-3 files were created
cd ..
ls *.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-*.deb

#reboot
reboot

#Check your new Kernel version
uname -r

#Check if Kernel HZ value change persisted:
cat /boot/config-`uname -r` | grep HZ

#If value 1000HZ=yes:

Done!;)
```

--===< Quick Tip >===--

If your running an "on-demand micro instance", compile time will take approximately **7hrs** and cost around **$0.14!**
If on the other hand you want to save yourself some time and recompile in just under **12min** for **$0.21**, you can do this:

- Reserve a High-CPU Extra Large Spot Instance (20x ec2 compute units, 7GB ram)
- Recompile your kernel with aforementioned commands (12min)
- Once recompile completes  take a snapshot of the spot instance's ebs volume
- Wait for Snapshot to complete (few minutes)
- Terminate the spot instance
- Create new volume from the snapshot (nichname: Volume X) also take note of the volume ID!
- Go to Instances > Create your New EBS Instance

  - This will be the New instance your Asterisk server will be running on
  - It must be from the same Base AMI, and same Zone as Volume X)
    -The New Instance will now be created along with a corresponding EBS Volume
- Stop the New instance
- Go to Volumes > Detach the New instance's corresponding EBS volume
- After it's detached, delete that volume
- Select Volume X > Attach to New EBS Instance (Device ID Must be: /dev/sda1)
- Go to Instances > Start your New Instance
- Re-associate your Elastic IP if you had one.
- Check if everything works
- If everything checks out, create another snapshot for backup!

Done! ;)

Big shout out and thanks to Redzarf, Eric Hammond, and John Johansen!

Comment: There is no need to terminate. You can simply stop and change instance type from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your second best guess is correct. Amazon's way of booting Linux kernels is special to their domain, and it is indeed as you mentioned - based on a special version of grub. They have published resources on the matter, please read [Enabling Your Own Linux Kernels](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?UserProvidedkernels.html).

Comment: Thanks. I still have the feeling the first guess applies too. The linked page was for SUSE and I've spent the day looking for instructions for Ubuntu without much luck :( Any pointers on doing it in ubuntu would be appreciated.